# http client frozes in windows form app

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am following [this example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client), and it works in a console application, but then I tried in a windows form app and it forzes, when in hits the line `await client.GetAsync("api/branches/1035")`
how is it diferent?

console code (this works):

```
static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49358/");

           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/branches/1035");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                branch branch = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<branch>();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}", branch.Id, branch.Color);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is frozen when it hits `await client.GetAsync("api/branches/1035")`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49358/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/branches/1035");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Branch branch = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Branch>();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}", branch.Id, branch.Color);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is your button1_Click still trying to write to the console? It's not a console application any longer.

Comment: @KenWhite yeah my bad, forget about that line, I am trying to get some "branches" from my api, then the client should return the ones he liked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing a deadlock that I [explain fully on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Essentially, an `await` will capture a "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. In the Console app, this "context" is the thread pool context, but in the UI app, this "context" is the UI thread context.

Further up the call stack, you're calling `Wait`, which blocks that thread until the task completes. In the Console app, the `async` method resumes on a thread pool thread; but in the UI app, the `async` method cannot resume on the UI thread (because the UI thread is blocked in the call to `Wait`).

To fix this, use `async` all the way:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await RunAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are waiting for the result of your async task.  That blocks the UI thread until that task is completed.

Do not wait for completion in your `button1_Click` event handler.

Comment: What do you want to do once the download is complete?

Comment: my app will read a list of branches, then the client will select some of those branches where should I place this?

Comment: You could disable any form elements that should not be interacted with before the HTTP request is completed (e.g. the ListBox for the branches), then re-enable that element at the end of your `RunAsync()`.  See http://www.danderson.me/posts/async-and-await-ui-synchronization-with-c-5-net-4-5-and-winforms/

Answer (score -1):

If you are executing this code in Windows Forms then you should use Messagebox.Show("Fetching data") and you will see that it will delay the Main from exiting. By this time your response will come.