# C# REST Client Web API GET Request using api key authentication

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I am building C# REST Client in windows form application project in VS 2017.

I have been following an excellent example from Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

I am trying to implement HTTP GET method to obtain a json data from a server. The server uses an api key for authentication and has to be included in the GET request path or url as follows:

```
"xyz.com/node?apiKey=12345"
```

I have tried to add this authentication header as follows:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            string ApiKey = "12345";
            string baseAddr = "http://xyz123.com/public/node";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddr);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("?apiKey=", ApiKey);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new     
System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue
("application/json"));

            // get node serial numbers
            try
            {
```

Although VS is not showing me any errors, I feel that there is mistake in which authentication header is added to include api key. Particularly in the line:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("?apiKey=", ApiKey);
```

No json object is being returned. The thread just terminates without any output.

Comment: The api key is part of the URL but you are trying to add it in the header of the request.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake placing the api key to DefaultRequestHeaders. Api key should be part of url. So instead of

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("?apiKey=", ApiKey);
```

try

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://xyz123.com/public/node");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
query["apiKey"] = "12345";
builder.Query = query.ToString();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.ToString());
```

or use [Handy extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28842400/245460) used in this SO answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am newbie to C#. I have worked with python and visual basic adequately. I am getting a syntax error for the line: var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query); Name 'HttpUtility' doesn't exist in current context. I have already used Systems.Web namespace. This line is under a statis async Task. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have referenced appropriate assembly? https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: System.web was missing in references. I added it. Based on your answer above, what should be the input argument to GetAsync call? `client.GetAsync(string url)` I have the following line of code: `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)`  isn't the <url> input argument same as client.BaseAddress? When this line is run, I do not get any output. It console output window says The thread 0x--- has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: The common solution is using constant part of URL as the base address (http://xyz123.com/public) and the variable part (node?apiKey=xxx) as the parameter for GetAsync.

Comment: Thanks. Can HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri) method used in a windows form application project? I create a new uri `Uri request_uri = new Uri("full path");` I pass this uri to HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri) method. `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);` As soon as this line is executed, The windows form (GUI) pops up and I get thread 0x-- has exited with code 0 (0x0) in the console output window. I also get The program '[17800] ProjectName.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff). Other synchronous calls like `WebRequest.GetResponse()` seem to work just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The full path in my previous comment is: "http://xyz123.com/public/node?apiKey=1234" has http + : + // in the beginning

Comment: I found out why my windows form app freezes [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316790/http-client-frozes-in-windows-form-app) Looks like a deadlock was created due to different thread type.Thanks for your previous help!

Comment: @Rock Ok, but why is this not accepted answer and not vote up?

Comment: I have already accepted your original answer. Regarding upvote, it says that since I am a new member, my vote is recorded but not publicly displayed